# Python multiprocessing manager alternative for shared state and worker coordination

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku, multiprocessing, shared-memory

My web app handles http requests using several workers. Workers use some shared state, which their actions sometimes update. So far I have used a separate script/process for initializing and managing that shared state, using multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager.

This means that state_manager script would start BaseManager server, to which workers would connect as they go up and send their requests. This used to work fine on heroku. Now I'm migrating to another hosting (virtual), which for some reasons disallows TCP sockets and state_manager cannot start its (localhost) server. For context, I'm getting:

[Errno 1] Operation not permitted

As mentioned, this server is purely for local interprocess communication.

What are my alternatives for this shared state and worker management?

P.S.

On Heroku I used gunicorn, new hosting uses Passenger, if this somehow helps.

EDIT: Error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "state_manager.py", line 207, in <module>
    server = manager.get_server()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 482, in get_server
    self._authkey, self._serializer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 139, in __init__
    self.listener = Listener(address=address, backlog=16)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 438, in __init__
    self._listener = SocketListener(address, family, backlog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 577, in __init__
    self._socket.listen(backlog)
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

Comment: Why you don't use threading for workers?

Comment: Because GIL prohibits true parallelism.

Comment: Do you really need true parallelism?

Comment: It would be preferable.

Comment: Manager uses sockets for communication across applications, you can search for that. I think your host service don't allows that.

Comment: I suspect these sockets are disallowed on my hosting.

Comment: Are you filling in the socket address yourself? `BaseManager(address=('', 50000), authkey=b'abc')` maybe a different host (e.g., 127.0.0.1 or 127.0.0.10) or a different port?

Comment: @tdelaney Error says `Operation not permitted`, so I don't agree with you. @Drinkwater may you give us full error massage?

Comment: Something like that. It won't work. I'm told working with sockets is blocked on kernel level.

Comment: If OS of your server computer is linux, you may try use [UNIX sockets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket-families).

Comment: @EkremDİNÇEL - Have you ever done socket programming? Some ports or interfaces may be restricted and you'll get this error. If you are working in a virtual environment you may well find that you can use some ports and interfaces but not others.

Comment: Maybe a database (e.g. sqlite) is best for this kind of thing after all...